# MySQL cannot allow to create a table with a column name DB_ROW_ID

Tags: mysql

I have a database in MySQL which using InnoDB engine. When I create a table having  column name DB_ROW_ID. a error message shows cannot allow to create a table with a column name DB_ROW_ID. Why?

Comment: Show the create Statement and the complete error message

Comment: Error Code: 1166
Incorrect column name 'DB_ROW_ID'

Comment: Please add bothe to your question using the edit function

Comment: sorry a typo mean both the create Statement and the error message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot create a table with a column name that matches the name of an internal InnoDB column (including DB_ROW_ID, DB_TRX_ID, DB_ROLL_PTR, and DB_MIX_ID). This restriction applies to use of the names in any letter case.

> mysql> CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT, db_row_id INT) ENGINE=INNODB;
>   ERROR 1166 (42000): Incorrect column name 'db_row_id'

Comment: But it will let you create a table called `table` and a column called `column` and an INT column called `INTEGER`.  Try CREATE TABLE test.`table` (c1 INT, `integer` INT, `column` varchar(12)) ENGINE=INNODB; Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.36 sec)  - Sigh

Comment: I have read about at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html